# Jpeg Color Compression Efficiency

Tags: colors, compression, jpeg, grayscale

Does anyone know the efficiency difference between:
1. Compressing an RGB image
2. Compressing each color of the RGB image seperately (compressing a "grayscale" image of R, then compressing a "grayscale" image of G, then compressing a "grayscale" image of B, so in the end you get 3 different compressed "grayscale" images...).

So for example if I take an RGB image and compress it to a certain quality (lets say it will take 1GB) and then take an R image and compress it to the same quality, will it take 1/3 the memory (0.33GB)? 
Or will the RGB image, due to the correlation between the different color images, be more efficient? By how much (50%/70%...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG almost never uses RGB. It converts the RGB image data to a different color space, YCbCr, to separate the luminance channel (Y) from the chrominance channels (CbCr). The chrominance channels are then usually reduced in resolution by a factor of four (a factor of two in each dimension, designated as 4:2:0) as the very first step in the lossy compression. This is to take advantage of the lower resolution of the human eye to color information.

Then each channel is compressed separately. There is not much correlation between the color channels, and even less with the (now) higher resolution luminance channel.

Comment: Looking at a YCbCr image, it appears that the images are somewhat correlated. I would guess that one might be able to reduce the overall size of the color image...   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr (image of the cabin in the mountains)

Comment: You can find papers where they try to mine what appears visually to be correlation. They don't get much mileage out of that.

Comment: Please update your answer; you imply that lossy JPEG compression requires color subsampling. There is an RGB option for JPEG images that Adobe created. It doesn't support subsampling (obviously) and effectively compresses each channel independently as the author asks. It doesn't seem to compress images any worse than YCbCr except that you save a little added error by not having to convert the colorspace to YCbCr and back again.